# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at registerNgModuleType

Tags: angular, typescript, typeerror

I updated my version of **Angular** from 8 to 9. Everything went well, the project builds, but when I go to http://localhost:4200/ I get a blank page, and there is such an error in the console in the browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Tried different methods: reinstalled all libraries and deleted node_modules.
None of the above helped.

Comment: I would recommend that you delete 'node_modules' folder completely and do a fresh install of the same.

Comment: @HarshSingla, I did this several times, but it didn't help

Comment: I am geting same issue. Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @Zeeshanef, unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as `ng serve` was completing sucessfully without producing any error. You need to run the `ng build --prod` and you will get the actual error messages which are existing in your modules file.